# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Encog.ML.Data.IMLData'

Tags: c#, parameters, encog

I am getting this error when trying to test my neural network with test example.

This is the line where error occurs:

```
 IMLData output = network.Compute(skuska1,testout1);
```

where skuska1 is input:

```
 double[] skuska1 = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\te1.txt").Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(double.Parse).ToArray();
```

and testout1 is desired output:

```
 double[] testout1 = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\te1out.txt").Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(double.Parse).ToArray();
```

For those who are not so familiar with encog, this is what is required for Compute method according to MVS 2012

```
 void BasicNetwork.Compute(double[] input, double[] output) (+1 overload(s))
```

What should I imagine under (+1 overload(s))?

Thank you.

Comment: `Compute` doesn't return anything (the method is void) so you can't do `IMLData output = network.Compute(skuska1,testout1);`.

Comment: Thank you, but before my modification there was this: IMLData output = network.Compute(pair.Input); where the pair consists of 2 double arrays. And It worked like that. How can i modify it if I would like to print out that output? for example Console.WriteLine(output); ?

Answer (score 2):

`void BasicNetwork.Compute(double[] input, double[] output)` feed Neural Netowrk with data from `input` and put output to `output`. That's why it returns `void`. So your code should loke like this:

```
   double[] output  = new double[skuska1.Length];
   BasicNetwork.Compute(double[] skuska1, double[] output);
```

And then you can compare your result from `output` with expected test output.